# Bootstrap 4 grid layout one row with three columns then another row after filling up the entire space with one column

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, razor-pages

I am trying to achieve the following format for my razor-page bootstrap implementation:

row

.col-8

.col-3 [nested]

.col-9 [nested]

.col-4

row

.col

|---|-----|----|

| ------------ |

This is what I currently have:

[image]

The green background signifies row 1, where the orange color is row 2.

I am guessing that row one is displaying like this due to the following code:

```
<div class="row" style="height:100vh;background:green">
```

When I change the starting row to this:

```
<div class="row" style="background:green">
```

I get this undesired layout:

[image]

I am trying to accomplish restricting the third column (large content) to the same height as the column on the left hand side.  vh-100 resolves it, but it creates a massive gap between row 1 and row 2.

I just want to make sure I follow best practices and not hard code the column to a specific max-height constraint.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the entire cshtml I am working with:

```
<div class="row" style="height:100vh;background:green">

    <div class="col-8 h-50">

        <div class="row h-100">

            <div class="card col-3 border-right-0 rounded-0">

                <img src=@string.Format("URI/{0}?height=250", Model.UserDisc.EmployeeId0) style="object-fit:cover;width:100%">

            </div>

            <div class="card col-9 rounded-0">

                <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">

                    <li class="list-group-item">@assocname</li>

                    <li class="list-group-item">@Model.UserDisc.Title0</li>

                    <li class="list-group-item">@Model.UserDisc.TelephoneNumber0</li>

                    <li class="list-group-item">@Model.UserDisc.EmployeeId0</li>

                    <li class="list-group-item">@Model.UserDisc.Sid0</li>

                    <li class="list-group-item">@Model.UserDisc.PhysicalDeliveryOfficeNam0</li>

                    <li class="list-group-item">@Model.UserDisc.HomeDirectory0</li>

                    <li class="list-group-item">

                        @if (!(Model.UserDisc.UserAccountControl0 == 512))

                        {

                            <a href="#" class="badge badge-danger">AD ACCOUNT: LOCKED</a>

                        }

                        else

                        {

                            <a href="#" class="badge badge-info">AD ACCOUNT: GOOD</a>

                        }

                    </li>

                    <li class="list-group-item">

                        Manager: @mg

                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalLong">

                            View Direct Reports

                        </button>

                    </li>

                </ul>

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

 

 

    <div class="col-4 h-50" style="overflow-y:auto">

        @{

            String isSearching = "visible";

            if (Model.CurrentFilter?.Length > 1)

                isSearching = "disabled";

            else

                isSearching = "visible";

        }

 

 

        <input class="form-control" id="myInput" type="text" placeholder="Search..">

        <div>

            Total Groups: @Model.UserGroupMembership?.Count

        </div>

        <table id="myTable" class="table table-bordered table-striped mb-0">

            <thead>

                <tr>

                    <th>Groups</th>

                </tr>

            </thead>

            <tbody>

                @foreach (var item in Model.UserGroupMembership)

                {

                    <tr>

                        <td>

                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)

                        </td>

                    </tr>

                }

            </tbody>

        </table>

    </div>

</div>

 

<div class="row container-fluid w-100 h-100" style="background:orange">

    <table class="table table-responsive" style="overflow:auto">

        <thead class="thead-dark">

            <tr>

                <th scope="col">

                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PCDetails[0].ResourceName)

                </th>

                <th>Status</th>

                <th>

                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PCDetails[0].CurrentLogonUser)

                </th>

                <th>

                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PCDetails[0].PrimaryUser)

                </th>

                <th>

                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PCDetails[0].LastLogonUser)

                </th>

                <th>

                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PCDetails[0].Manufacturer)

                </th>

                <th>

                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PCDetails[0].Model)

                </th>

                <th>

                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PCDetails[0].SerialNumber)

                </th>

                <th>

                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PCDetails[0].Architecture)

                </th>

                <th>

                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PCDetails[0].OSCaption)

                </th>

                <th>

                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PCDetails[0].OSInstallDate)

                </th>

                <th>

                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PCDetails[0].LastHardwareScan)

                </th>

                <th>

                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PCDetails[0].LastBootupTime)

                </th>

                <th>

                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PCDetails[0].CNIsOnline)

                </th>

                <th>

                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PCDetails[0].CNLastOnlineTime)

                </th>

            </tr>

        </thead>

        <tbody>

            @foreach (var item in Model.PCDetails)

            {

                var style = "offline";

                if (item.CNIsOnline == true)

                {

                    style = "online";

                }

                <tr>

                    <td>

                        @{

                            var n = item.ResourceName;

                        }

                        <a href="../Clients/Details?id=@n">@n</a>

 

                    </td>

 

                    <td>

                        @if (style == "online")

                        {

                            <a href="#" class="badge badge-success">ONLINE</a>

                        }

                        else

                        {

                            <a href="#" class="badge badge-secondary">OFFLINE</a>

                        }

                    </td>

 

                    <td>

                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CurrentLogonUser)

                    </td>

 

                    <td>

                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PrimaryUser)

                    </td>

 

                    <td>

                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastLogonUser)

                    </td>

 

                    <td>

                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Manufacturer)

                    </td>

 

                    <td>

                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Model)

                    </td>

 

                    <td>

                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SerialNumber)

                    </td>

 

                    <td>

                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Architecture)

                    </td>

 

                    <td>

                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.OSCaption)

                    </td>

 

                    <td>

                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.OSInstallDate)

                    </td>

 

                    <td>

                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastHardwareScan)

                    </td>

 

                    <td>

                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastBootupTime)

                    </td>

                    <td>

                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CNIsOnline)

                    </td>

                    <td>

                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CNLastOnlineTime)

                    </td>

                </tr>

            }

        </tbody>

    </table>

</div>
```

UPDATE:

I ended up modifying the right column table div to the following:

```
<div class="wub" style="overflow-y:auto;max-height:50vh;overflow-x:hidden">
```

I didn't realize I could use anything other than ***100vh*** for that property.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your table HTML mind the quotes:

```
<table id="myTable" class="table table-bordered table-striped mb-0" ">
```

A simple copy/paste into a jsfiddle points you to this issue.

(issue) https://jsfiddle.net/tive/gya9zu2k/1/ (ln: 103)

---

My suggestion is to not mix the column structure with content.

1. Remove the `100vh` on the first row.
2. The `h-50` or `h-100` classes should go on your content, inside a column
3. Use a wrapper for your dynamic height on the groups
4. Similar for your card layout, the card is placed inside a column. Not the column is now a card, that's mixing structure and content.

---

```
<div class="your-wrapper" style="overflow-y:auto;max-height:100vh;">
    <table id="myTable" class="table table-bordered table-striped mb-0"></table>
</div>
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/tive/gya9zu2k/)**

Comment: Thanks for catching that, the issue still exists where row 1 still has a big gap before I see row 2.  Updated original post to reflect the quote fix you had mentioned.

Comment: I've reviewed your question and hopefully came up with a solution. If not, please elaborate on how exactly you want this displayed.

Comment: Thank you to point me in the right direction, it's much appreciated.  I have updated my OP with what I ended up going with.